# Toggle multiple values of a typescript interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an action bar in Angular 12, with several icons. When user clicks on one of them, a new division/Panel opens up. Now, when one icon is clicked, only that panel has to open up, and the others are closed.
I created an interface for setting which panel is active.

```
export interface PanelModel{
  apps : boolean;
  payroll: boolean;
  chat : boolean;
  mycloud: boolean;
}
```

In my service I have initialized the Interface with

```
public chosen: PanelModel = {
   apps:false,
   payroll:false,
   chat:false,
   mycloud:false
};
```

Now if apps icon is clicked, I would like to set the this.chose.apps = true and then set payroll, chat, mycloud variables to false.

How do I set the values of the interface?

Comment: Logic could be simpler to represent which panel is active as a string union (type CurrentPanel = 'Apps' | 'Payroll' | ...` or to use an `enum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to iterate through the keys and dynamically set the selected icon to true and the rest to false, so if this is the case then the below should solve your issue.

```
// Your interface.
interface PanelModel{
  [apps: string]: boolean;
  payroll: boolean;
  chat : boolean;
  mycloud: boolean;
};

// Object that implements your interface with default values.
const chosen: PanelModel = {
 apps: false,
 payroll: false,
 chat : false,
 mycloud: false
};

// Your clicked icon (as an example).
const clickedIcon = 'apps'

// Log what it looks like before.
console.log('BEFORE: ', chosen);

// Iterate through the keys to find the one to set to true and set rest to false.
Object.keys(chosen).map(key => {
    if(key === clickedIcon) {
        chosen[key] = true;
    } else {
        chosen[key] = false;
    }
});

// Below is doing the same as above but in a single line of code.
// Object.keys(chosen).map(key => key === clickedIcon? chosen[key] = true : chosen[key] = false);

// Log output.
console.log('AFTER: ', chosen);
```

Since you specifically mention Angular 12, you can hook the button click to a function which passes the $event (name of icon or whatever) to a method which does this iteration specifically. (assuming your rendering your buttons dynamically then you can pass the name directly rather then event)

```
// Method in your typescript component file
  onIconClick(tabName: string): void {

    Object.keys(chosen).map(key => {
      if(key === tabName) {
        chosen[key] = true;
      } else {
        chosen[key] = false;
      }
    });
  }

// Your HTML component file (if buttons a rendered dynamically)
<div *ngFor="let tab of tabs">
  <button type="button" class="button (click)="onIconClick(tab)">{{tab}}</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Excellent! I did try to use the Object.keys function, but did not realize that my main mistake was to declare the interface as const. I kept getting an error that chosen[keys] is not valid. Then i was naturally helpless.

Comment: sorry, but when i define the interface as const, then i get the following error:TS1248: A class member cannot have the 'const' keyword.

Comment: Also, if i try with readonly, i get the following problem TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type PanelModel'.No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PanelModel'.

Comment: I think I figured the problem out. We need to define the interface with [key: string]: boolean; in the beginning. Then its solved!! If you could update that in your answer, then we can close it. Unless you have another way to solve the typescript errors i mentioned above

Comment: Basically you mean declare a variable or a constant that implements your interface. See updated interface which should help